# Substituting label using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I want to modify my labels "CA Vex Eté Mé  (Cou)" with the substitution option (my qgis version is 3.22)

I don't understand why for this label it doesn't work.

Is it related to parentheses or I s there a function that would allow me with a rule to get a result?

I tried the replace function but I can't do it either.

I have an idea:

[image]

Comment: It looks are there are two spaces between `Mé` and  `(Cou)`, while your expression contains only one, so the texts are different and the substitution won't be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set rules to use your substitution text ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Mr_Yum for your help, but that's not exactly what I was looking for.
I wanted to substitute the entire word for another (not sure why it doesn't work with the 'whole word' option).
On the other hand, by unchecking this option, it works perfectly.

[image]